# Trying to replicate old code, migration guide unhelpful

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms

I am trying to replicate and update some old code that had some aqua imports. Unfortunately the [migration guide on github](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua#migration-guide) is unhelpful and [the one it links](https://qiskit.org/documentation/aqua_tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.html) is broken.
It has the following imports:

```
from qiskit.aqua import run_algorithm
from qiskit.aqua.input import LinearSystemInput
from qiskit.quantum_info import state_fidelity
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms.classical import ExactLSsolver
```

I cannot find information on any of these and would like help with migration.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiskit Aqua was deprecated just over 2 years ago. The migration guide was published in the main Qiskit docs for some while - you can still find the source, a notebook which you can view, in the Aqua repository [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/main/docs/tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.ipynb).

From the imports above, it seems like the code you are looking at was around linear solvers and HHL. Those imports though look old, even for Aqua, and were related to a declarative way of defining a problem that was removed sometime even before Aqua was finally deprecated.

Linear solvers, including HHL, was moved from Qiskit Aqua to Qiskit Terra. This function is still in the latest released version, but it was deprecated a while ago and will finally be removed in the next release. The code was moved into a separate repository, ahead of this next release, which you will find linked in the [Qiskit Textbook section on HHL](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/solving-linear-systems-of-equations-using-hhl-and-its-qiskit-implementation) under Qiskit implementation. This HHL is a different implementation, than that which was in Aqua, so I suspect you will more need to redo things based on what you want given the imports/function you show were not even supported in Aqua when it was deprecated.